# Combine multiple xml tags

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, parsing

I have some problem with xml in Sql Server. I can't combine multiple xml tags in one variable sql.

I need to combine **first_name**, **last_name** and **father_name**.

```xml
<BODY>
  <type>insert</type>
  <table_name>Customer</table_name>
  <First_name>Мирмухаммедов</First_name>
  <Last_name>Мирмухаммедов</Last_name>
  <Father_name>Rahmonovich</Father_name>
  <Birth_date>12.12.2018</Birth_date>
  <Country>Dushanbe</Country>
</BODY>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean with *combine*? Do you want to place these elements within a common parent element `<Person>`?  Or do you need them concatenated as one string (btw: You should not do this!!!). Show your code, show the expected result and describe what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @fullName=CONCAT((select T2.col.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(200)') from @XML.nodes('BODY') T(c) Cross APPLY t.c.nodes('/BODY/*') as T2(col) where T2.col.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(200)')='First_name'
),' ' +(select T2.col.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(200)') from @XML.nodes('BODY') T(c) Cross APPLY t.c.nodes('/BODY/*') as T2(col) where T2.col.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(200)')='Last_name'
),' '+(select T2.col.value('.[1]','VARCHAR(200)') from @XML.nodes('BODY') T(c) Cross APPLY t.c.nodes('/BODY/*') as T2(col) where T2.col.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(200)')='Father_name'
))
```

Comment: Too complex and inefficient query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
set @fullName = (
    select CONCAT
    (
        c.value('First_name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)'),
        ' ',
        c.value('Last_name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)'),
        ' ',
        c.value('Father_name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(200)')
    )
    from @XML.nodes('BODY') T(c)
)
```